# I need to use Asp-net Identity Role and user management with Azure AD Role and User Management together in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

Integrate Azure AD authentication with asp.net core identity individual accounts

- Users can authenticate against my local database using the standard method
- Users can authenticate against Azure Active Directory

Works fine with either one of the above But i need to use both for Authentication and Authorization for my application

where Azure AD and Asp.net will have groups and users of its own the roles will be configured in the application

What i have tried is :

For Azure Authentication

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options => {
           options.AddPolicy("Admins", policyBuilder => 
           policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:AdminObjectId")));
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("Users", policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureSecurityGroup:UserObjectId")));
            });
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

And for AspNet Identity

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

So what i need is

1) Need to Use both role and user management of Azure AD and AspNet core Identity in same Application

2) User should able to login through Azure AD and AspNet Identity and use the same roles such as (Admin,User) for both Azure AD and AspNet Identity Users

Comment: have you figured out how to do this ?